# jQuery not displaying appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I drop a debug point in my source file I can see the following image:

[image]

But when I remove this debug point, I only see the following:

[image]

The change in color is affected by an overlay with some opacity.

The relevant code is:

```
  flashSuccessMessage = function(msg) {
    $('#overlay').hide();
    var $ch = $("#content-header");
    $ch.after('<div id="flash_message" class="alert"></div>');
    var $fm = $("#flash_message");
    $fm.addClass("alert-success");
    $fm.append(msg);
    $fm.show().children().show();
    $fm.fadeOut(3000);
    $fm.empty();
  }
```

And in this case msg is "Job Type Added Successfully"

I can't understand why I only see the message when I break on the execution after the point where I call $fm.append(msg);  It doesn't matter which I break on after that (of the three lines), it will appear.  When I don't have any break and let the page execute the script, the green alert appears but no words.

Any ideas?

I've tried various jQuery methods here - instead of .append() using .html() for example, and I've tried inserting the msg inside the  with the flash_message id to begin, tried inserting the message wrapped in

tags, tried re-ordering things, (but I need to clear the contents of this div at the end...)

I've used jQuery's .delay() method, etc.  Is it jumping to executing .empty() despite other elements using a timer to fully execute?

Comment: Your `$fm.empty();` empties the content and removes the message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a callback to your `fadeOut` so that the contents aren't emptied until `$fm` is completely hidden:

```
  flashSuccessMessage = function(msg) {
    $('#overlay').hide();
    var $ch = $("#content-header");
    $ch.after('<div id="flash_message" class="alert"></div>');
    var $fm = $("#flash_message");
    $fm.addClass("alert-success");
    $fm.append(msg);
    $fm.show().children().show();
    $fm.fadeOut(3000, function(){   // empty() is not called until
      $(this).empty();              // the animation is complete
    }); 
  }
```

Without the callback, the `empty()` method is being triggered immediately after `fadeOut()`. This causes the content to be emptied BEFORE the animation is complete.

More information on jQuery's fadeOut method can be found [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Answer (score 0):

The animations in JQuery are asynchronous, so the code keeps executing while the animation happens. .fadeOut has a completion block which you can read about at http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/.

So, instead of calling fm.empty() after your animation, you should put it inside a function and pass that function into fade out. That function will then run after the animation completes.

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to clear the contents of this div at the end...

Use `html` instead of `append`:

```
$fm.html(msg);
$fm.fadeOut(3000, function(){
  $fm.empty();
});
```

Check doc of [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/):

```
.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

> complete
> Type: Function()
> A function to call once the animation is complete.